# Output on Linux not going to the next line

Tags: bash, shell

I'm new to Linux and want to ask how to make some output using a bash script.
I can print like this

```
1
2
3
```

but how would I make something like this

```
1,2,3
```

I have scrolled through many sites, but can't seem to find a clear description of how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Your current program uses `echo`, which by default writes its text followed by a newline. You can tell it to avoid the newline but it's probably better to use a tool that doesn't write the newline in the first place

```
#!/bin/bash
first=yes                               # First time through the loop
for (( i=10; i<=20; i++ ))              # Loop from i=10
do
    [[ -z "$first" ]] && printf ", "    # Print a comma unless first time through
    printf "%s" "$i"                    # Print the number (as a string)
    first=                              # Not the first time through
done
printf "\n"                             # Final newline
```

You could just post-process the output from your original script, but this is prone to breakage as soon as you include spaces in your original output

```
./yourscript | xargs | tr ' ' ,
```

Generally it's better to create the correct output in the first place.

Comment: im really thankful, this really help me a lot. once again thank you

Comment: Do you understand what I've done here? Do experiment with changing the code to learn what would happen

Comment: `man printf` will help